# speeding up a query on MySql

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a table with more than 10 million rows and 10 fields(columns). There is an index on field_1 and I am running the following query.

```
create table t2 
select field_1,
       sum(ifnull(field_2,0)) as field_2, 
       sum(ifnull(field_3,0)) as field_3,
       sum(ifnull(field_4,0)) as field_4 
from t1 
group by field1;
```

The data type of all the columns is varchar(200).

This query is not able to produce the result even after running for more than 1 day. Any suggestions on getting the results quickly will be helpful.

Comment: Do you really name your tables and columns like this (`field_1`, `table2`, ...)?

Comment: Which columns are varchar(200)? The source columns or the target columns? GROUP BY on 10 million rows will probably take a while.

Comment: Not to mention the conversions of 3x10M values from varchar to numbers so the SUMs are performed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) on your SELECT to reveal which indexes it's using.
2. Tune your query and repeat step 1 until satisfied.
3. Create your new table with the desired structure.
4. Use [INSERT ... INTO new table SELECT FROM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) ... old table replacing the select part with the SELECT query you tuned in step 2.